# Incrementar columnas en PHPExcel

Tags: php

Estoy utilizando PHPExcel y necesito realizar un For incrementando la columna ,Por ejemplo:

`for ($i = 'J'; $i <= 'J' + $num; $i++) {
     $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
             ->setCellValue($i . '11', $cabecera[$j]);
     $j++;
 }`

$cabecera es un arreglo con una cantidad variable de elementos y son los textos que deseo imprimir en el excel a generar y $num es la cantidad de elementos que posee este arreglo.

Al ejecutar el código veo que la varibale $i se incrementa correctamente .
Para $num = 3  debería de imprimir hasta la columna 'L' ,pues entiendo que
:
`'J' + $num = 'M' y 'L' < 'M'`

Sin embargo el proceso no sale del For y sigue incrementándose

¿Alguien pude orientarme en como puedo realizar este incremento de columnas según la cantidad de elementos de un arreglo ?

Comment: https://ideone.com/8cysbq chequea el stdout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba de la siguiente manera entendiendo que el 11 de la siguiente línea nunca va a cambiar de valor:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
             ->setCellValue($i . '11', $cabecera[$j]);
```

El código sería el siguiente:

```
$column = 'J';
for ($i=0; $i<num; $i++) {
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
             ->setCellValue($column . '11', $cabecera[$i]);
    $column++;
}
```

Comment: Me sirvio,gracias por la ayuda